# How can $e^a = 0$ when integrating?

Tags: integration, exponential-function, polar-coordinates

I was doing a question which asked me to turn the following into polar equation:$$(y + x − x(x^2 + y^2))\frac{dy}{dx} = y − x − y(x^2 + y^2)$$

With a lot of messy algebra I can get it down to:
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln \left\lvert\frac{{r^{2} - 1}}{r^2}\right\rvert = \theta + k.$$
Which is definitely correct. From there:
$$\pm{e^{2\theta+2k}}=\frac{r^2-1}{r^2}$$
let $e^{2k}=A$
$$\pm{}Ae^{2\theta}=1-\frac{1}{r^2}$$
$$1\mp{Ae^{2\theta}}=\frac{1}{r^2}$$
$$r^2=\frac{1}{1\mp{Ae^{2\theta}}}$$
As $ A>0$ and $e^{2k}\neq0$, where $C\neq0$
$$r^2=\frac{1}{1+Ce^{2\theta}}$$
At this point, I'm asked to sketch the graph for the different possible values of C, which I assumed meant for $C>0$ and $C<0$, however apparently $C=0$ is valid. I'm struggling to grasp why it's possible. Would that mean that $k=-\infty$? If anyone can explain this / correct any issues with my working, I'd greatly appreciate it

Comment: If $C = 0$ then you have $r^{2} = 1/1 = 1$? This is simply a circle about the origin with unit radius.

Comment: I'm aware that's what it would look like to sketch, I'm just not sure why you're allowed to have C as 0

Comment: If $C$ is an constant of integration (which is what it looks like) then it can have any value, i.e. $C \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: C is just a constant, not a function

Comment: That's what I meant, apologies

Comment: But $A=e^2k$, and I don't see how that can be 0

Comment: If we accept that $k \in \mathbb{R}$ as it is a constant of integration, then naturally, as $\exp(x) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{+}$ then we can have $\exp(k) = 0$ for some value of $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with set notation, is there another way you can explain it to me?

Comment: 1) I think you forgot a few parentheses in your first equation. 2) I suspect that your "definitely correct" formula is at least is imperfect (what if $r < 1$?). My guess is that you were not careful enough about definition domains while integrating $-(r(1-r^2))^{-1}$. 3) Then there's Andrew D. Hwang's answer, which is correct.

Comment: 1) Feel stupid for missing out those parentheses, it's been fixed. 2) Again, you're right. Was just a slip up with the coefficients of logs though, the steps after that are correct

Answer (score 10):

Let's look at a simpler (but otherwise analogous) example:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = y.
$$
The usual method of solution is to separate variables, integrate, and solve for $y$:
$$
\frac{dy}{y} = dx,\qquad
\ln|y| = x + C,\qquad
y = Ae^{x},\quad A = \pm e^{C}.
$$
(The choice of signs arises when dropping the absolute value from $y$.) Now, $e^{C}$ cannot be zero, but the $A$ in the formula $y = Ae^{x}$ can certainly be zero. Why did our method not see this solution?

Our first step was to divide by $y$. If $A = 0$, then $y \equiv 0$, and our very first step becomes nonsensical. In other words, our method of solution implicitly omitted the case $A = 0$.

Nonetheless, it's trivial to verify that $y = 0$ *solves the ODE*.

---

In your situation, you've lost the constant solution $r = 1$ at the first expression following "after a lot of messy algebra...":
$$
\ln \left\lvert\frac{\sqrt{r^{2} - 1}}{r}\right\rvert = \theta + k.
$$
Nonetheless, $r = 1$, a.k.a. $x^{2} + y^{2} = 1$, presumably satisfies your ODE. (It doesn't appear to be a solution as typed, however....)

Comment: Thanks so much, understand this so much better now. just after the "messy algebra" was $dr/d\theta=r^3-r$, where I'm obviously dividing by 0 for r=1

Comment: You're very welcome. (And with the latest edit, it's clear $r = 1$ is a solution. :)

Comment: Yeah, small mistakes make a big difference. Need to be more careful

Answer (score 1):

The basic point, I think is this.  A family of solutions of an analytic differential equation, given by an analytic function with a parameter, will be valid on any connected open set of values of the independent variable and the parameter, as long as you stay in the region of analyticity.  So even if you assumed $C > 0$ in your derivation of the solution, the final result  will be good for all $C$, as long as you avoid singularities.